# How can I mimic alt-tabbing between windows using divs in a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a plugin or a way to mimic alt-tabbing between windows using divs in a web page. To clarify, the user will not be pressing alt-tab, but will alternate between the divs with the mouse.

To be precise:

- I need to popup a set of divs
- That the user can navigate left or right, similar to alt-tabbing between windows.
- The center div should be large and the side divs should be increasingly smaller.
- When the user moves the mouse cursor left, it should rotate the list right, moving the center div to the left.
- I also want it to work with swipe events on a touch device (but I can implement that separately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should work:

- [jcoverflip](http://www.jcoverflip.com/)
- [Content Flow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/)

Let me know if they aren't what you're looking for (and why).